# To which number does 1/p converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

To what number does the following series converge:

$\displaystyle S = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{11} + \dots$

And maybe second question is whether there is a nice way to write this value (like $\ln(\pi)$) or is it calculated using brute force?

Links are appreciated can't find much about this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function

Comment: It doesn’t converge

Comment: Perhaps a more directly useful link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes

Comment: Note that this diverges very, very slowly so it may appear as if it converges if you take partial sums.

Comment: Hmm weird I would say theres no way this can diverge but okay. Quiet sure I'm wrong then if euler says so:-).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems ; The second theorem shows that the series grows like $\ln(\ln(n))$ that means that even the primes upto $10^{100}$ give a small sum. This is the reason why it is so difficult to detect the divergence. Calculating the partial sums directly (even with all available computational power) would surely lead to the wrong conclusion that the series converges.

Comment: There is an even stronger result even more incredible : Let $a$ and $b$ be comprime positive integers. Then the sum of the reciprocals of the primes of the form $an+b$ ($n$ positive integer) diverges !